Incorrect processing of "Enter" press on tag merge
In tag merge tool (available to site moderators) it's possible to select target tag from dropdown list, e.g.:



You can use either mouse or keyboard to confirm the choice. Unfortunately if you use a keyboard (by pressing Enter) the resulting tag is extracted from the editbox (i.e. "кли") instead of the dropdown ("клиент", currently highlighted item). That leads to undesired behavior and invalid tag is selected as the target. See animation below:



I used only keyboard to type three starting letters, then use arrow down to select "клиент (46)" item, pressed Enter to confirm, and got final step window with "client -> кли" tags to merge. That's not what I expected to see.

Probably items of the select or the select itself isn't keyboard-focusable. Then pressing Enter clicks the button "Preview Merge" instead of select's option.
